# Mortgage calculator validation input error

Tags: c++, validation, input

I'm trying to write a mortgage calculator that follows the following rules:

- Takes 3 input parameters

  - 1 of data type double specifies loan amount
  - 2 of data type double specifies yearly interest rate ex (7.50)
  - 3 of data type int specifies the number of years to pay back the loan.
- Returns a value of a monthly payment 
  Must validate the paramters
- Amount 1 thousand and 1 million loan amount
- Int rate between 2-20%
- Number years between 5-30
- If any are invalid should return -1.0

My code is throwing the following error, and I'm not sure why:

```
filename.cpp(36) : error c2181: illegal else without matching if
```

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

double loanAmount, yearlyIntRate, yearsOfLoan;

void main()
{
double  amountPaidBack, interestPaid, monthlyPayment;
double commonTerm, numerator, denominator;
cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << endl;


cout << "Lets figure out how badly you got screwed on your house loan\n Enter your loan amount in dollars." << endl;
cin >> loanAmount;
cout << "Enter your yearly Interest Rate as a percent. ";
cin >> yearlyIntRate;
cout << "Enter your term of loan in years. ";
cin >> yearsOfLoan;

if (loanAmount > 999 && loanAmount < 1000000 && yearlyIntRate> 1.99 && yearlyIntRate < 20.01 && yearsOfLoan <= 30 && yearsOfLoan >= 5)
commonTerm = pow(1 + yearlyIntRate / 1200,
yearsOfLoan * 12),
numerator = (yearlyIntRate / 1200) * commonTerm,
denominator = commonTerm - 1,
monthlyPayment = numerator / denominator * loanAmount,
amountPaidBack = yearsOfLoan * 12 * monthlyPayment,
interestPaid = amountPaidBack - loanAmount;
cout << " Your monthly payment will be.\n " << monthlyPayment;
cout << "\n And you paid " << interestPaid << " in interest over the term of the loan." << endl;

else if (loanAmount < 1000 && loanAmount < 1000001 && yearlyIntRate < 2.00 && yearlyIntRate > 20.00 && yearsOfLoan > 30 && yearsOfLoan < 5)
cout << "That is invalid input data" << endl;
}
```

Comment: You have lots of commas where there should instead be semicolons.

Comment: Also, you have no indentation, which makes your code very difficult to read (and thus difficult for you to debug).

Comment: Also the body of the if statement should be in { }.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you have several commas that should be semicolons.

The second problem is that the following If statement:

```
 if (loanAmount > 999 && loanAmount < 1000000 && yearlyIntRate> 1.99 && yearlyIntRate < 20.01 && yearsOfLoan <= 30 && yearsOfLoan >= 5)
```

has no opening / closing curly brackets `{}` and hence it will be parsed to execute the first line after it if the condition is true.

Hence, at the statement:

```
else if (loanAmount < 1000 && loanAmount < 1000001 && yearlyIntRate < 2.00 && yearlyIntRate > 20.00 && yearsOfLoan > 30 && yearsOfLoan < 5)
```

the previous If statement has already been processed by the parser, and this else is not related to any If statment.

To correct this simple add curly brackets `{}` enclosing the code that should be executed should the previous If statement succeed.